# How to forward HTTP request in JAX-RS

Tags: java, apache, jersey, jax-rs

What is the equivalent of `requestDispatcher.forward` in JAX-RS?

```
httpRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/" + getViewType(httpRequest) + "/login.jsp").forward(httpRequest, servletResponse);
```

Actaully i want to make GET call to a JSP page from rest service developed using JAX-RS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use exactly the same code with JAX-RS.
Use `@Context HttpServletRequest` to get the `httpRequest`.

Comment: Is it really a JAX-RS approach? [`HttpServletRequest`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/requestdispatcher) seems to be part of Servlet specification rather then JAX-RS - its [javadoc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.1/apidocs/) doesn't contain such class.